# Getting value from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0

I'm writing a PowerShell script to read a CSV.  I have everything working so far, it's able to find the value from user input (branch number) and finds the values that have "Y" in the available.  Please see 2nd picture.

First picture is my CSV file.

This is what I need help with.  How would I get the value of the first available CoreID?  In this example, FMD354800000.  Once I get the first available CoreId, I want to change the Available to N

[image]

[image]

```bsh
$Find = $ImportCSV | Select-String -Pattern $GetBranchNum

$Find -match "Y"

New-ItemProperty -path $CoreIP -name "TTable ID" -PropertyType String -Value "Test" -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Import-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) to import the CSV:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv'
```

Since the file seems to be fixed width you'll need to `Trim()` fields before checking their value.

```
$branchNumber = '8000'

$first = $csv | Where-Object {
    $_.'Branch Number'.Trim() -eq $branchNumber -and
    $_.Available.Trim() -eq 'y'
} | Select-Object -First 1
```

This filters the CSV for records with the given branch number that have a value `Y` in the field `Available` and selects the first matching record.

Then change the value of the `Available` field of that record:

```
$first.Available = 'N'
```

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\sample.csv'
PS C:\> $csv

Branch Number      CoreID            Available
-------------      ------            ---------
8000               FMD354800000      Y
8000               FMD354800001      Y
8000               FMD354800002      N

PS C:\> $first = $csv | Where-Object {
>>   $_.'Branch Number'.Trim() -eq '8000' -and
>>   $_.Available.Trim() -eq 'y'
>> } | Select-Object -First 1
>>
PS C:\> $first

Branch Number      CoreID            Available
-------------      ------            ---------
8000               FMD354800000      Y

PS C:\> $first.Available = 'N'
PS C:\> $first

Branch Number      CoreID            Available
-------------      ------            ---------
8000               FMD354800000      N

PS C:\> $csv

Branch Number      CoreID            Available
-------------      ------            ---------
8000               FMD354800000      N
8000               FMD354800001      Y
8000               FMD354800002      N
```

Neither `Select-String` nor the `-match` operator are particularly useful in this context, so don't use them.

Comment: Thank you, checked as answer

Comment: Sorry, one more question,  after I set the value to 'N', how would I save the CSV so that the CSV file is updated from 'Y' to 'N'?

Comment: Normally with `Export-Csv`. That would add double quotes around the values, though. If you want to preserve the original format (including spaces) you probably need to write each record as [custom-formatted](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) line.

Comment: I added this to make available to "N", and export csv to the original csv file`$First.Available = "N" | Export-Csv \\hqfs1\users\tantony\PowerShell\GetCoreID\CoreID.csv`

Comment: It's deleting everything in the csv, and showing this #TYPE System.String
"Length"
"1"

Comment: `$First.Available = 'N'` doesn't produce output, so the pipeline passes `$null` to `Export-Csv`, which then correctly creates an empty file. Leave the line alone and create the CSV from `$csv`: `$csv | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType`

Comment: I'm sorry, but when I type in `$csv: $csv | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType`, it says Variable reference is not valid ':'

Comment: This is the very last step that I need help, everything else is working, new to powershell

Comment: The statement you're supposed to run begins *after* the colon. I thought that was obvious. Remove the `$csv:`.

Comment: I actually did that after I posted the comment, now I have `$First.Available = "N"   
        
        $CSV | Export-Csv '\\hqfs1\users\tantony\PowerShell\GetCoreID\CoreID.csv' -NoType`, but still same thing, it's deleting the csv file and it says "Length" "53" in the csv.  Everything else is deleted.

Comment: Didn't I already tell you to leave the line `$First.Available = "N"` alone? Put the export in a new line.

Comment: Yes, export is in a new line, I have `$First.Available = "N"` in one line, and `$CSV | Export-Csv '\\hqfs1\users\tantony\PowerShell\GetCoreID\CoreID.csv' -NoType` in another line.  I didn't know how to put that in the comment, sorry

Comment: Then you somehow converted `$csv` to a string. Please re-read my answer and follow the instructions.